# Request to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I need to execute the following request to the MySQL server from symfony.

```
SELECT  count(DISTINCT hotel_id) FROM symfony.search_result where request_id=@requrst_id
```

Code:

In controller:

```
  $qwery2=$repository->hotelsCount($searchId);
```

Function:

```
 public function hotelsCount($requestId){

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('self');
        $qb->select('count(hotel_id)')
        ->where('self.request_id=:req_id')
        ->setParameter('self.req_id',$requestId)->getQuery()->getResult();
        $rez=$qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
        var_dump($rez);
        return $rez->fetchAll();
    }
```

But i got error:
[Semantical Error] `line 0, col 13 near 'hotel_id) FROM': Error: 'hotel_id' is not defined.`

Table: [image]

Comment: What is the entity name?

Comment: neme: 'SearchResult'

Comment: Remember you are building DQL not SQL, camelCase should be the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `count(self.hotel_id)` in your select
or `count(self.hotelId)`. And in your where: `self.reqId` < check the entitys for that

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new myself, so I admit I didn't completely follow your code, but try single quotes around 'hotel_id'

Answer (score -1):

Try this, in this case, entity name is "SearchResult" and  bundle name is "AppBundle", change it if is needed.

```
public function hotelsCount($requestId) {

     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();  

     $qb->select('count(p.hotel_id)');
     $qb->from('AppBundle:SearchResult', 't')
         ->where('p.request_id = :id')
         ->setParameter('id', $requestId);

     $count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

     return $count;
}
```